# Two jquery plugins to the same textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a text area.I am using texteditor plugin to convert the text area to a text editor.Again I am connecting the same textarea to another plugin which does some other work.But the second plugin is not working in this way.I i remove the texteditor plugin then the second plugin works fine.I am unable to understand the problem.

my code: The following js connects the text area having id="ha" with htmlbox pugin.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#ha").css("height","100%").css("width","100%").htmlbox({
toolbars:[
    [
    // Cut, Copy, Paste
    "separator","cut","copy","paste",
    // Undo, Redo
    "separator","undo","redo",
    // Bold, Italic, Underline, Strikethrough, Sup, Sub
    "separator","bold","italic","underline","strike","sup","sub",
    // Left, Right, Center, Justify
    "separator","justify","left","center","right",
    // Ordered List, Unordered List, Indent, Outdent
    "separator","ol","ul","indent","outdent",
    // Hyperlink, Remove Hyperlink, Image
    "separator","link","unlink","image"

    ],
    [// Show code
    "separator","code",
    // Formats, Font size, Font family, Font color, Font, Background
    "separator","formats","fontsize","fontfamily",
    "separator","fontcolor","highlight",
    ],
    [
    //Strip tags
    "separator","removeformat","striptags","hr","paragraph",
    // Styles, Source code syntax buttons
    "separator","quote","styles","syntax"
    ]
],
skin:"blue"
    });


});
```

The following js connects the my another plugin with the same textarea "ha"

```
$(document).ready(function() {


var language="hindi";

 $('#ha').myPlugin({

   language : language,
   rApi :"xxxxxxxxxxxx",
   rAppId:"xxxxxxx",

 });

});
```

If I don't connect the textarea with the first plugin then the second plugin works but if two plugins are connected with the textarea "ha" then only the first works.

Comment: Have you tried placing both plugin calls under one same "ready" event?

Comment: Yes,I did try.Does not working.

Comment: And you get no errors in the console? You've tried calling them in the opposite order?

Comment: Console is not giving any error.I tried to call them in opposite order too.

Comment: A quick google search makes me think the jQuery htmlbox plugin has its own API to interact with it's textarea data. If the second plugin has something to do with the textarea data it's probable it's trying to modify it's content using standard methods, not the new API provided by htmlbox.

So, either the second plugin has a compatibility mode with the textarea plugin or you'll have to change / update the plugin functionality.

Comment: what is `myPlugin` doing? `htmlbox` will hide the `textarea` and will render the editor. so certain events on the `textarea` you are attaching to with `myPlugin` wont fire, ie `keyup`, etc.

Comment: Yes,Now I understood the reason.Is there any plugin available that converts the textarea in an editor but still we can still do work with the textarea data?

Comment: show the myplugin code.

Comment: Bootstrap HTML5 WYSIWYG Rich Text Editor have solved the issue as it does not stop the text area data to be applied with another plugin.